# Social implications of complete separation of copulation and reproduction

Tags: science-based, society, psychology, reproduction

*The Twelve Kingdoms* is a fantasy novel series written by Japanese author Fuyumi Ono, and has been made into an anime series.

In this series, humans, and indeed all other motile beings, are born of fruit that grow on special trees.

In the case of humans, a fruit occurs when a couple (implied to be male and female) weave a special ribbon and tie it around the branch of a birthing tree while praying for a child, and if their prayers are granted, a new fruit begins to grow at the point where they tied their ribbon, taking nine months to mature. Humans in this world do not reproduce sexually.

However the series also depicts the existence of establishments either strongly implied or directly stated to be brothels, implying that the humans of this world are *at least* superficially anatomically identical to humans from Earth, a supposition reinforced by the existence of humans transplanted between Earth and the Twelve Kingdoms, who are regarded by the locals as seeming somewhat odd, but not excessively so, and certainly not anatomically different (except for certain Twelve Kingdoms individuals who possess human level intelligence and size, and are born from human birthing trees, but resemble other species, and who are not depicted as ever having arrived on earth).

So, we have in The Twelve Kingdoms a clear separation between reproduction and copulation. The existence of brothels would imply that copulation is as pleasurable for the inhabitants of the Twelve Kingdoms who reproduce externally as it is for humans on Earth, who reproduce sexually.

Evolution favours sexual reproductive practices based around the relative energy investment of each parent, so that in general, male mammals tend to be far less sexually selective than females due to the fact that the female must expend far more energy in reproduction, and in humans who use copulation as a social bonding activity, concealed estrus means that females must always be selective lest they become pregnant.

However, in the Twelve Kingdoms, there is a clear separation between copulation and reproduction, so logic would suggest that since copulation is a pleasurable activity that has zero potential future energy investment in an offspring, it should be a common practice, yet the series depicts prostitution in a negative fashion equivalent to prevailing attitudes toward prostitution on Earth.

Finally, in the Twelve Kingdoms, the overall public health status of each of the kingdoms appears to be a function of the virtue of that kingdom's monarch, and does not seem to be organic in nature.

Could a world similar to the one described in this series justify the apparent contradiction between the complete separation of copulation from reproduction and the consequential logical biological and sociological evolution of its inhabitants, and the existence of brothels which attract significant levels of public disapproval despite there being no apparent sociobiological reason for that disapproval?

Comment: It may be possible to divine an historical anticedent for this (in social/biological evolutionary terms) if you tell us how they actually reproduce. However unless this is specified in the novels it's purely speculative. Better still, why not ask it on [scifi.se] to see if there's cannon relating to this?

Comment: *So, why in-universe is there such....* is this a question about an anime series? If so it is not a good fit for WB.SE but would be a good question on Anime.SE. In fact, there are two answers on the egg part [one on myths](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4437) that lead to this and one [on the historical basis](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3478) on that site. If it is about building a world, I suggest an edit removing the look for in-universe explanations

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows there is a historical perspective - it just has nothing to do with world building - during the Three Kingdoms period (after Han before Jin) [for which the anime is based](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/817/do-the-various-kingdoms-in-the-twelve-kingdoms-have-historical-basis) - women could be seen as commodities with [the practice of concubines](https://asiasociety.org/education/women-traditional-china) & [courtesans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_ancient_and_imperial_China#Tang_dynasty). I would add as an answer but its not WB

Comment: I think questions regarding established third party invented worlds of this sort ought to be asked in [SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions) or Anime as already suggested. WB.SE is designed for questions about making your own invented world. VTC as off topic; but really should be exported.

Comment: The book/anime series is the source of the scenario,  but my question is coming from a worldbuilding point of view: Could there be something that I've missed, or does this scenario have a fundamental flaw?  An in-universe explanation is required for internal consistency.   I already know that the *real* reason is authorial bias.

Comment: In what way are you "coming from a worldbuilding point of view"? You're asking a question about a world which has already been built and have given no indication that you're in a position to build it further. This question appears to be about established facts in an existing IP, thus it belongs on the Anime or SF&F stack, not WB.

Comment: in my opinion (never watch the anime) it probably because its depict as tarnishing the marriage or bonding culture with lust not love, or the prostitute maybe from slavery or related with other black bussiness, or just culture/people bias without any basis reason.

Comment: Brothels aren't frowned upon in our world because the prostitutes might become pregnant. So the same reasons that exist for us are valid for them.

Comment: Your edit leads me to think that the question might be answerable, but the tags may be in error at present. A political answer comes to mind, but politics is not is ultimately divorced from biology and society (which are not divorced from each-other). Have you looked at posting this in the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to get it sorted out?

Answer (score 5):

Biologically speaking you are correct of course; copulation has no energy investment in it for the future in the setting you describe. But I think the better question in this universe is why would two people put a ribbon on that tree in the first place? What ties them together so tightly they are prepared to make that energy commitment together?

In humans at least (and there is some evidence that for other animals, including some birds), mating is as much about building an emotional connection as it is an investment in reproduction. That is to say, that in order for two people to want to tie that ribbon on the tree, they need an emotional connection that in our current biology is tied to the act of copulation because in our world copulation and procreation are effectively the same thing.

In this world you describe however, copulation may well have evolved with the singular purpose of inciting an emotional bond that leads to a decision (and a conscious act of volition) to procreate. When you think about it, it may well be that copulation in this world is designed as an emotional bonding tool because the physical procreation model has in effect atrophied - that is to say, non-sentient animals can't tie ribbons to trees and pray, so they probably procreate the old fashioned way. Humans in this universe have transcended this approach but the act of copulation is a vestige of that time before transcendence which remains to incite the emotional connection needed for a couple to procreate.

In such a world, prostitution would indeed be considered a base profession because it is perverting the intent of copulation - it's taking advantage of the pleasure without engaging the emotional commitment. In such a case, it is still a cheat or subversion of the original intent, even if pregnancy can't occur.

In the end, it's bordering on a story-driven question and is potentially primarily opinion based, but I think there is a strong case here for the separation of the biological and anthropological imperatives, and copulation could easily fill the latter even if the former is now managed by other means. This would also explain why it still exists in a world with birthing trees in the first place.

Comment: It is stated in the books & anime, as well as in my question, that even animals are born from the fruits of trees... just not the same trees as humans.

Comment: If copulation is used to build and sustain an emotional connection,  a situation should exist with young adults and older unattached persons being highly promiscuous,  and becoming less so as they find a compatible long-term partner, and in such situations, the implied 'brothels' would be more like night clubs, but *shouldn't* be disapproved-of

Comment: Instead, there is no directly implied copulation at all other than in the brothels, which 'are not good places to work'.

Comment: @MontyWild the fact that you keep replying to the answers with clarification on how the Anime works (its established world) further shows that this would be better asked on a site where you would be able to find people already knowledgeable about that world (like Anime.SE). Here - the answers are all likely to impose their own thoughts on how to alter that world because that is the focus of WB.SE (as that would be world building)

Comment: @JGreenwell, I'm not interested in how the world is said to work according to canonical sources, I'm interested in the apparent contradiction between those canonical sources  and the facts of reproductive biology and sociology.

Comment: @MontyWild and that is an excellent WB question (but not how your current question is written): I'd remove the reference "in-universe" and instead make it "How might a world similar to the one described in this Anime justify the apparent contradiction between the lack of need for sexual reproduction and these biological and sociological evolution and the popularity of brothels?" (or something similar - shouldn't reference canonical sources as again - that's their world the answer is "cause author wanted it")

Comment: @MontyWild much better with edit (I would consider adding politics as a tag since your looking for "*socio*biological" answers - and its likely that there may not be biological - or at least purely biological - answer)

Answer (score 0):

> (...) when there are no conceivable negative consequences that people working in any other profession that brings them into close contact with other people would not experience?

Your argument is invalid because, wxcept within the realm of pornography, other professions do not risk you getting an STD from their practice.

There is a very clear line between prostitution and... Well, not-prostitution. If a masseur gets an STD from his job, he was doing more than just massages at the parlor.

I don't think it's fair to nurture negative feelings towards prostitutes, I save that for the economical systems which make that the only way for some people to earn a living. But it's kinda predictable that when the whole town starts developing gummas rhe populace will go mad, and then the witch hunt begins.

Comment: As I have said, in this world,  disease happens when the monarch is corrupt, *not* when pathogens are communicated to a non-immune person.

Comment: "Finally, in the Twelve Kingdoms, the overall public health status of each of the kingdoms appears to be a function of the virtue of that kingdom's monarch, and does not seem to be organic in nature."